# Questions about construction of Lebesgue measure in Rudin's RCA

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have questions about the construction of Lebesgue measure in Rudin's RCA (Theorem 2.20).

1. On pg52, Rudin defines $\lambda(E) = m(E+x)$ for measurable $E$ and says that $\lambda$ is a measure. But, why is $E+x$ measurable?
2. In the same paragraph on pg 52, Rudin first shows $\lambda(E) = m(E)$ for all boxes, then using the observation he makes in the preceding paragraph, he shows $m(E+x) = m(E)$ for all Borel sets $E$, then finally he says the same equality holds for every measurable $E$, by using 2.20(b). But, can't I make the same conclusion without using 2.20(b)?  Theorem 2.18 shows the regularity $\lambda$ and $m$, so the conclusion holds immediately. Doesn't it?

Comment: $E+x$ is measurable either by looking at the definition of measurable, or by using the fact that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.

Answer (score 3):

1. There are many ways to show this. Suppose $E$ is measurable, then by that we mean there exists $A\subset E \subset B$, such that $B$ is a $G_\delta$ set and $A$ is an $F_\sigma$ set,and $m (B \setminus A) = 0$. Now, denote  $K_x=K+x$ for any set $K$. We notice $B_x \setminus A_x = (B\setminus A)_x$. We would like to show $m (B_x \setminus A_x) =0$, and it's enough to show that translation maps null sets to null sets.
   Let $N$ be a null set, then we notice that for any cover $\{ B_n^{\epsilon} \} $ of open cubes (or dyadic, or closed...), such that  $m( \bigcup B_n ^{\epsilon}) < \epsilon$. By Taking finite unions and intersections we may take disjoint cubes. Now; The collection $\{ (B_n ^\epsilon)_x \}$ is a cover of $N_x$ with the measure (or volume, since we're talking about cubes). This is easy to show, each cube in the collection retains its volume.Now, because $\epsilon$ is arbitrary - $N_x$ is null set.
2. The corollary of 2.18 is relevant to *Borel* measures, meaning, this is true for any set $F$ in the Borel collection, but the Lebesgue collection is larger, and at first sight it is unclear if a completion of a regular measure is still regular (with respect to the, perhaps, greater collection of sets).

Comment: What is $m^*$? Is it the same as $m$?

Comment: $m^*$ is the outer measure defined by: $m^*(E)= \inf \{\sum_{k=0}^\infty m(B_k) \mid E \subset \bigcup B_k\, .\, B_k\in\mathfrak{A} \}$ where $\mathfrak{A}$ is the collection on which $m$ is defined. I see now that Rudin uses another, equivalent definition of Lebesgue measurability, see my edit to my answer.

Comment: If you look at the proof of the corollary 2.18, Rudin constructs a regular measure $\mu$ satisfying the conclusions of Theorem 2.17, and $\mu$ from Theorem 2.17 is in turn from Theorem 2.14, and that $\mu$ is defined on some collection that is larger than the Borel collection.

Comment: When Rudin says "Borel measure", he sometimes means a measure defined exclusivley on the Borel collection, but in other cases he means a measure defined on some collection that contains the Borel collection. Doesn't he?

Comment: For your first comment: I agree with you that the proof of Thm 2.18 is "almost" (up to a few words here and there) is exactly what is needed in showing that Lebesgue measure is regular.

Comment: For your last remark: Yes, you are right, and i must add it is quite common to mix this things. This is because knowing that a measure is defined on the Borel collection is the essence of some of its properties, although it might be defined on a bigger collection. The Lebesgue measure is an extension, or completion of the Borel-Lebesgue measure (which is the Lebesgue measure restricted to the Borel set), But because it is a completion of a regular measure - it is regular, and the regularity is established by the fact that it is indeed a Borel measure.