# Showing the Regularity of any Positive Borel Measure $\lambda$ in Theorem 2.20 of Rudin Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

$\lambda$ is given as any positive Borel measure on $R^{k}$ and $\lambda\left(E\right)=m\left(E\right)$ for all boxes $E$.

A box is defined in 2.19 of RCA (Please let me know if I should provide it here). The measure $m$ satisfies the properties of the Riesz representation theorem (Theorem 2.14).

Rudin concludes that $\lambda$ is regular using Theorem 2.18. This theorem (2.18) gives conditions for $\lambda$ to be regular which is that every open set is $\sigma$-compact (countable union of compact sets) and $\lambda\left(K\right)<\infty$, where $K$ is any compact set belong to the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra.

But I am not sure how Theorem 2.18 can be used as above (as it is done in Theorem 2.20) without knowing that $\lambda\left(K\right)<\infty$, where $K$ is any compact set belong to the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated. I could be missing something simple, hence am happy to delete the question if this is too trivial.

Related Posts:

[Questions about construction of Lebesgue measure in Rudin's RCA](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957223/questions-about-construction-of-lebesgue-measure-in-rudins-rca?rq=1)

Comment: Compact sets are bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any compact set $K$ is  subset of some box $B$. So $\lambda (K) \leq \lambda (B)=m(B) <\infty$.

Any compact set is bounded. Hence it is contained in a box $\left(0,\delta\right)$ for large enough $\delta$. Hence, $\lambda\left(Q\left(0,\delta\right)\right) =m\left(Q\left(0,\delta\right)\right) = \delta^{k}<\infty$. Here, we are using property (a) of Theorem 2.20, which is that $m\left(W\right)=\text{vol}\left(W\right)$ for every $k$-cell $W$.

Comment: Why is a compact set $K$ a subset of some box $B$ and why is $m\left(B\right)<\infty$? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @texmex Any compact set is bounded. Hence it is contained in $Q(0,\delta)$ for large enough $\delta$. $m(Q(a,\delta)) = \delta^{n} <\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, Much appreciative of your helpful explanations.